# php: replace numeric ids with associative keys

Tags: php, url-parsing

I'm working on a function that should parse an url to create an associative array.

I'm having trouble replacing numeric keys with their proper string equivalent.

For instance, `http://localhost/fr/user/edit/5/?foo=bar&love=hate`  produces

```
Array
(
    [langue] => fr
    [app] => user
    [action] => edit
    [id] => 5
    [0] => user
    [1] => 5
    [foo] => bar
    [love] => hate
)
```

what i would like is:

```
Array
(
    [langue] => fr
    [app] => user
    [action] => edit
    [id] => 5
    [foo] => bar
    [love] => hate
)
```

Here is my function so far:

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($url);

// 1./ "folder path" into array
$values = explode('/', $url['path']);
unset($values[0]);

// 2./ "url variables" into array
parse_str($url['query'], $vars);
$url = array_merge($values,$vars);

// 3./ remove empty values
$url =  array_filter($url);
print_r($url);

// 4./ replace numeric keys by the application vars
$keys = array('langue','app','action','id');
$count = 0;
foreach($url as $key => $value)
{
    if(!is_string($key))
    {
        $first_array = array_splice ($url, 0,$count); 
        $insert_array  = [$keys[$key] => $value ];
        unset($url[$key]);
        $url = array_merge ($first_array, $insert_array, $url);

    }
    $count++;
}
print_r($url);
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove numeric keys from array ?

Comment: yes, indeed, as stated in my second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to remove numeric keys.. So do like this

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    'langue' => 'fr',
    'app' => 'user',
    'action' => 'edit',
    'id' => '5',
     0 => 'user',
     1 => '5',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'love' => 'hate'
);

$arrNew = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
if(is_numeric($k))
{
unset($arr[$k]);
}
}

print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [langue] => fr
    [app] => user
    [action] => edit
    [id] => 5
    [foo] => bar
    [love] => hate
)
```

**EDIT :**

Since **`unset()`** didn't work for you. Try this approach.

```
$arrNew = array(); //We have a new array
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
if(!is_numeric($k))
{
$arrNew[$k]=$v;//Pushing the things to new array. 
}
}
unset($arr); //Deleting the old array to save resources
print_r($arrNew);//Printing the new array [The Output will be same as above]
```

Comment: That would work if i added one more step. I'm concerned with efficiency, so I would like to run only one loop. Can you fuse this in my (step 4) loop? That's what i'm failing to manage right now. seems unset($url[$key]) does not work.

Comment: Thank you. Using another array is a good idea. I've found what i think is the best solution thanks to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the numeric keys from array.you can try this code :

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_int($key))
    {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: that would remove some values of the array, which i need. I want to replace numeric keys by literal keys, not remove.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way to do it, tipped by +shankar-damodaran idea to use another array.

```
<?php

function route($url = NULL){
    if(!$url){
        $url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $url = parse_url($url);

    // 1./ "folder path" into array
    $values = explode('/', $url['path']);
    unset($values[0]);

    // 2./ "url variables" into array
    parse_str($url['query'], $vars);
    $url = array_merge($values,$vars);

    // 3./ remove empty values
    $url =  array_filter($url);

    // 4./ replace numeric keys by the application vars
    $keys = array('langue','app','action','id');
    $url2 = [];
    foreach($url as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!is_string($key))
        {
            // remove
            $key = $keys[$key];
        }
        $url2[$key]= $value;
    }
    return $url2;
}
// Example use
$route = route();
print_r($route);
```

Comment: You can `unset($url);` array to save resources ;)